# gnu screen on redhat enterprise, %H doesn't output hostname

Tags: gnu-screen

I've had a screenrc that has worked for years on multiple boxes

```
caption always "%{kW}[%H]%{Wb} %-Lw%{kY}[ %n %t ]%{-}%+Lw %=%{kW}[%D %Y %m %d %c %]"
```

I've put my trusty .screenrc on a new box, and it seems as if %H no longer prints hostname.  The color commands work (%{ky}) as well as the screen number (%n) & title (%t).   just seems % outputs the same as %n, but only in some cases.  The title shows up just fine.  Colors show up just fine.

For debugging, i put this line in, and got the following output:

```
caption always " =%H= =%= =%n= =%t= "

 =0H= =0= =0= =bash=
```

UPDATE: it seems like %+w or %-w don't work either, tho %w does